# sharp can't be installed using npm

Tags: node.js, bash, npm, sharp

when running

`npm install sharp`

gives me the following error

```
npm ERR! code 127
npm ERR! path /root/.nvm/versions/node/v16.18.1/lib/node_modules/sharp
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command sh -c -- (node install/libvips && node install/dll-copy && prebuild-install) || (node install/can-compile && node-gyp rebuild && node install/dll-copy)
npm ERR! sh: node: command not found
npm ERR! sh: node: command not found

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2022-11-20T16_25_03_851Z-debug-0.log
```

how can I overcome this ?

Note 
node version

```
v16.18.1
```

npm version

```
8.19.2
```

when running sh command and then node -v
gives the following

```
[root@Monitor ~]# sh
sh-4.2# node -v
v16.18.1
sh-4.2#
```

Comment: It looks like it can’t find the command `node`. Are your sure its installed in your PATH?

Comment: Also, can you edit this question to add the log it mentions in the error message?

Comment: how could I ensure that node is installed in my PATH ?

Comment: It looks like `node` is node defined inside `sh` command. What operating system do you use?

Comment: @KonradLinkowski centos 7.8

Comment: I would run `sh` and then `node -v` and see if it's installed